# What is the result of adding a char and an int?

Tags: c++

When executing this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

   int a = 5;
   char x = 'b';

   std::cout << "The Answer is" << std::endl;
   std::cout << a+x;
}
```

I get the output:

> The Answer is
>   103

Why does this happen?

Comment: The ascii value of `'b'` is `98` see this: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Do you really need a full HD screenshot to convey the value `103`?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Now that's a pretty large font...

Comment: If you right click on the text in the command window you can mark then select and click again. The text is copied to the clipboard which can be added to your question as text (which is preferred here over a picture of your screen)

Comment: It's a [usual arithmetic conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions).

Comment: I actually expected it to crash ... But thanks for the help I learned something new !

Comment: @RuhanUR Please don't use screenshots for text.

Comment: ok.. I just thought this was a glitch or bug so I added a picture

Comment: No worries. Also do check out the other improvements I made, like removing chatty lines or the tag from the title, for future questions.

Comment: cool.. Now the question is Understandable

Comment: If you start doing a lot of math using `char` and relying on its implicit conversion to `int`, keep in mind that `char` can be signed or unsigned.  It's platform dependent.  So if you need it to be one or the other, explicitly use `signed char` or `unsigned char`, or use the `c & 0xFF` trick to force the `int` value to be in the 0 ... 255 range.  (The trick presumes 2s complement.)

Comment: @Eljay `char` need not even have 8 bits, but granted, those who work on systems where it has more than 8 usually know this anyway.

Comment: Although I don't think i would be using char to do math But @Eljay I will try and experiment with those c & 0xFF trick you said Just for funs.. Also curiosity.. I will search those tricks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you add a `char` to an `int`, the (p)r-value created is promoted to an `int`. Therefore what is printed is the `int` equivalent to the sum of the (usually) [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) value + the int.

The ASCII value of 'b' is `'b' == 98`. Therefore `98 + 5 == 103 (integer)`.

Comment: Now i get it ! Now it makes Sense ! Btw does it only work for letters Or does it even work for mathematical symbols as well like +,- ?

Comment: @RuhanUR: Any `char` literal like `'+'` will be promoted to at least an `int` when used in an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @RuhanUR Yes, it works for a lot of symbols (including +, *, space, '1'). Check the **hyperlink** on the answer

Comment: Well, not actually ASCII itself, but always the execution character encoding. (See the relevant compiler option: /execution-charset,  -fexec-charset, ….)

Answer (score 6):

`a + x` is evaluated as `a + (int)x` as the `x` is promoted to an `int`.

`a` is 5. The value of `x` depends on the *encoding* used by your platform; most likely ASCII, which is 98. The result 103 is attained.